# Ghostscript: how to reduce file size of large PDFs without changing smaller PDFs

Tags: ghostscript, filesize, downsampling

I am using GhostScript to convert large batches of PDF to PDF to reduce file size. The original PDFs vary in size and quality. Where there is a low quality, small file size (<350kb) PDF the output from Ghostscript is often poor.

Is there a way I can get GhostScript to ignore files below a certain size and just pass them through without downsampling?

Current settings:
SearchablePDFSetting=-dColorImageResolution=120 -dMonoImageResolution=38 -dMonoImageDownsampleType=/Average -dOptimize=true -dDownsampleColorImages=true -dDownsampleGrayImages=true -dDownsampleMonoImages=true -dUseCIEColor -dColorConversionStrategy=/sRGB -dFIXEDMEDIA -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=596 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=834

Thanks,
Vix

Answer (score 1):

The pdfwrite device can already pass images (not files) through without downsampling, there is no way to 'pass through without changing' a *file*. If you want to not process files below a certain size, then don't process them.

To avoid further downsampling of images, you need to add the 'xxxxImageDownsampleThreshold' parameters (one each for Mono, Grey and Color). If you set this to (eg) 1.5 then images which are up to 50% higher resolution than the target resolution won't be downsampled.

Note that you haven't (apparently) set a GrayImageDownsampleResolution, you haven't set the downsample type for Color or Gray images and a MonoImageResolution of 38 looks pretty ugly to me.

The default Gray image filter is DCT (JPEG) as is the Color filter. If the original image was DCT then applying a second round of DCT compression will result in ugly artefacts, especially if the image is *not* downsampled. I would suggest you change the filter type to FlateEncode.

All these options are documented in ps2pdf.htm in the Ghostscript doc folder.

Answer (score 0):

Add the option:

```
-dPDFSETTINGS=/screen
```

This "selects low-resolution output similar to the Acrobat Distiller 'Screen Optimized' setting."